# Flutter keyboard overlapping issue not solved with resizeToAvoidBottomPadding

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Basically I have a login page where I first segement into 2 container with one covers 55% and 45% of the screen. Then on top of these 2 container I add one more container with top 40% of the screen size and in it I have one more container which hold my user name and password text field. So on the design wise I am ok.

Now the issue when the keyboard comes the password field is totally not visible. First I just had stack then I did google and some suggest to put the Scaffold and add this line resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false, but seems does not work for me either too.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: Container(
        child: Stack(

      children: <Widget>[

        // The containers in the background
        new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .55,
             //color: Colors.blue,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
               image: new DecorationImage(image: new AssetImage("lib/assets/cbg.png"), fit: BoxFit.cover,),
             ),
            ),
            new Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .45,
              color: Colors.white,
            )
          ],
        ),
        // The card widget with top padding, 
        // incase if you wanted bottom padding to work, 
        // set the `alignment` of container to Alignment.bottomCenter
        new Container(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
              top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .40,
              right: 20.0,
              left: 20.0),
          child: new Container(

            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .45,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: new Card(
              color: Colors.white,
              elevation: 4.0,
              child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),

              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .05),
new TextFormField(
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Enter Email",
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          borderSide: new BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.blue
                          ),
                        ),
                        //fillColor: Colors.green
                      ),
                      validator: (val) {
                        if(val.length==0) {
                          return "Email cannot be empty";
                        }else{
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: "Poppins",
                      ),
                    ),
SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .05),
new TextFormField(
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Enter Password",
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          borderSide: new BorderSide(
                          ),
                        ),
                        //fillColor: Colors.green
                      ),
                      validator: (val) {
                        if(val.length==0) {
                          return "Password cannot be empty";
                        }else{
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: "Poppins",
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              ),
              )
            ),
          ),
        ),

        new Container(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
              top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .80,
              right: 50.0,
              left: 50.0),
          child: new FlatButton(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text("Press Me"),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),

        new Container(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
              top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .90,
              right: 50.0,
              left: 50.0),
          child: new FlatButton(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text("Forgot Password ?"),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        )   






      ],
    )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

After the changes the keyboard still appear a slight covering the textfield.

[image]

Can I achieve some

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should put all this inside a ListView, then when you open the keyboard the list will scroll up.

Comment: where to add the list which section?

Comment: I tried some thing like this  child:ListView(
                
                  children: <Widget>[
              
              
               Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                
                SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .05), ..... but it does not work either

Comment: Wrap the body with the list view,  'body : ListView(children: <Widget>[ Container (...) ] )'

Comment: still the same effect not changes. But the entire page can be scroll a litte

Comment: I think that i'm found your problem, change the ` resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,` for ` resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true, ` .

Comment: Yes I . have done that but still the keyboard cover a little of the password field

Comment: But did you take off the listview ?

Comment: No I didnt remove the listview should I remove it

Comment: Because if I remove I get this error  A RenderFlex overflowed by 282 pixels on the bottom. and with the settings resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,

Comment: I have updated my question with 2 screen shoots if you see the keyboard slightly cover the line of the password text field. How make the keyboard appear cleanly below it.

Comment: @newbie did you solve this? I am seeing the same issue

Comment: @blacj try to put into listview but not a very good solution though

Answer (score 2):

I'm 2 years late on this and you might find the solution already, but this is for someone who struggle to find the solution. (Include myself a couple a days ago)

To solve this, The "TextFormField" widget need another attribute called "scrollPadding".

```
TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:40), // THIS SHOULD SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: title,
        hintText: title,
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
        ),
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
      ),

      validator: (String? value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return title;
        }
        return null;
      },

    ),
```